# scanning strings and ints from stdio in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read two ints and a string input from stdio in this format:

```
22 CHEESE 2
```

into two different int variables and a string variable, as seen below.

```
        int newId, newQuantity;
        char newName[20];
        scanf("%d %s %d",&newId, newName, &newQuantity);
```

The code properly reads the string, but immediately after the inputs are entered, when I test to see what the value of newId and newQuantity are, they are always these large ints that are never what I input. I check for the change in inputs by modifying my code to show the following:

```
        int newId, newQuantity;
        char newName[20];
        scanf("%d %s %d",&newId, newName, &newQuantity);
        printf("%d %s %d",&newId, newName, &newQuantity);
```

and when I input 22 CHEESE 2, for instance, it prints -1957382872 CHEESE -1957382868. I was wondering if there was any way of rectifying this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you printing them? Please post [MCVE]

Comment: Please show how you "test to see what the value of `newId` and `newQuantity`" are. My guess is with `&newId` and not `newId`.

Comment: That code should work.  Add a test for the return value from `scanf()`; it might return `EOF`, `0`, `1`, `2` or `3` — and only if it returns 3 is everything OK.  You need to show us your printing: you may have written `printf("%d %s %d\n", &newId, newName, &newQuantity);`, but you don't want those `&`s.

Comment: I just edited the original post to show how i'm testing the values. My apologies, this is my first post on stack overflow, haha.@eugene

Comment: Notice how the values printed are different by 4, and the two variables are defined right next to each other.... just saying. Your code has undefined behaviour, but just happens to print the *address* of those two variables.

Comment: If this is your first post, you might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is a simple typo in printf... The `&` in front of newId and newQuantity is to give scanf the "address" of the where newId and newQuantity are in memory, so that scanf can store the values there. When you use `printf` you need to remove them (otherwise you're print the memory address not the value stored at it).

Comment: @jonathan that did the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This `printf("%d %s %d",&newId, newName, &newQuantity)` is wrong and should be `printf("%d %s %d",newId, newName, newQuantity)`, and is something you would have discovered if you *enabled compiler warnings*.

Here is the warnings:

```
$ gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:18: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%d %s %d",&newId, newName, &newQuantity);
                 ~^        ~~~~~~
                 %ls
main.c:7:24: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%d %s %d",&newId, newName, &newQuantity);
                       ~^                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       %ls
```

This question is a PERFECT example of why you always should provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you ask a question. The problem was not where you thought it was, but instead in code you did not show us at first. It is also a perfect example of why you should have compiler warnings enabled and read them. They often provide very good clues. A warning is the compilers way of saying "This code is valid, but it probably does not do what you want."